# How to convert VAE L2 Reconstruction Loss to a Log Likelihood

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have been puzzled trying to convert MSE to Log Likelihood in VAEs. Relevant Questions:

[What is bits per dimension (bits/dim) exactly (in pixel CNN papers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423120/what-is-bits-per-dimension-bits-dim-exactly-in-pixel-cnn-papers/431012?noredirect=1#comment835018_431012)

[Why is mean squared error the cross-entropy between the empirical distribution and a Gaussian model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288451/why-is-mean-squared-error-the-cross-entropy-between-the-empirical-distribution-a/288453)

Relevant Discussion: [Reddit: [Discussion] Calculation of bits/dims](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/56m5o2/discussion_calculation_of_bitsdims/)

In the paper: [Masked Autoregressive Flow for Density Estimation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07057.pdf)

They provide a formula from going from "Pixel space" to logit space, but I don't understand the logic behind it.

[image]

They normalize the pixel values and then multiply by some hyper parameter that is chosen arbitrarily.

They then derive this formula:

[image]

<strike>For which it is not clear if $x_i$ is an image in the dataset/batch or a pixel of image $x_i$ (most likely the later one but still unsure)</strike>

For which $x_i$ is a pixel value of image x.

But it is not clear what is p(x) for my VAE trained on MSE.

Answer (score 2):

> They normalize the pixel values and then multiply by some hyper
>   parameter that is chosen arbitrarily.

Actually, they're scaling and shifting an interval [0,255] to be [$\lambda,1-\lambda$], then applying logit to. Logit can't handle 0 or 1 as you know: $\mathrm{logit}(x)=\ln\frac x {1-x} $, so they have to put a floor and a ceiling on its inputs. They floor $\lambda$ is  *arbitrary* in some sense.

They also "dequantize" the pixel values, by adding random noise, so the values become, sort of, continuous.

> For which it is not clear if $x_i$ is an image in the dataset/batch or a
>   pixel of image $x_i$ (most likely the later one but still unsure)

They denote $x$ the set of pixels of an image which has D pixels, but in *logit* space. So $x_i$ would be a pixel in *logit* space. The result of the formula is a density bits per pixel, which they get from $p(x)$ - density in logit space.

Comment: so is $p(x)$ calculated directly from the $x=$ relationship?  if so what is it exactly in practice?

Comment: in the paper in this particular equation it's the density directly from the model. remember they logit transform the 256 bit pixels, z space, into x space which is "almost" $x\in [-\infty,\infty]$. the model fits to this space, and produces p(x) density, that's what they use in this equation

Comment: Sorry it is still not clear to me where to calculate the $p(x)$ from in the VAE context.

Comment: Would you please explain what is "Density"? It'd be great if you can provide some actual example.